# Buttons in android studio aren't working with OnClickListener()

Tags: java, android

Imagebuttons and button arent working. I tried diff ways but still  nothing. Used to work 2 days ago, didnt change anything and after opening app they just dont want to work whatever i tried (just new ones that i add)Even tried to copy and paste the code from my old app where they work but still nothing. I have been trying for 2 days now but can't get them to work. Please help:)

```
`


``
package com.example.planer;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.planer.R;

import java.util.Random;

public class daily extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.daily);

        Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prijavise4);
        final TextView textGenerateNumber7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);
        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(daily.this, daily2.class));
                setContentView(R.layout.daily2);}

        } );}}


and manifest;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Planer"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".Pocetna"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".mjeseci"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".daily"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".daily2"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>



I tried this method and in onCreate 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Created activity_main");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUserTypeOnButtonClick();
}``
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve when `onClick` is invoked?

Comment: Can you please share the XML layout file of `daily`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jbmcle just when i click on the button to load another page. It very simple app nothing special, just basic beginner "project"

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DFBBC5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="719dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.35"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_9" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName57"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.592" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName53"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName50"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.711" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/generatenumber4"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/prijavise4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/prijavise4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prijavise4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prijavise4"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_200"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:text="prijava"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"

        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:iconPadding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.89"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.696" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName51"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.741" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName58"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.621" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName59"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.56" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName49"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.68" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName10"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.092" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName11"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName12"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.169" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName39"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.985"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName13"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.212" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName14"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.252" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName47"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.404" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName46"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.373" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName45"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.342" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName40"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.252" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName41"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.27999997" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName44"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.31" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName15"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.292" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName16"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName17"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.374" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName79"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.374" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName20"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.415" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName21"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.454" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName22"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.495" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName23"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.536" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName24"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.576" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName25"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.617" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName26"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.659" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName27"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.699" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName28"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.738" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName29"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.781" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName30"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.82" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.062"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/weekly" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_width="488dp"
        android:layout_height="346dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="610dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_11" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/generatenumber"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView22"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.344" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress4"
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView22"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.62" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress5"
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView22"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).